# In Azure DevOps sprint items - Is there a way to share comments with the team, without the client seeing?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

thanking you in advance for helping me out.

Does anyone know if there is a way to enter information on an item without the client seeing it? Is there a plugin or extension I can install?

Comment: maybe there is a plugin (but I doubt that, as there is no api for that and it goes against the devops philosophy), but you certainly cannot do that with the default ui

Comment: There is no way to do this on work items. You could maybe record your comments in a Wiki that's not visible to the client but I'm not sure if that would help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,you can not use the azure devops to enter information on an sprint item without the client seeing it.Even if your grant the [Stakeholder access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops) for your client,they also can see the information about the sprint item.
If you just want to share your completed sprint plan and inform other members of your team or organization.You can click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/share-plan?view=azure-devops).

Hope this helps and have a nice day!